# Managed Metadata Column crawled, but not mapped to managed property

Tags: search, managed-property, crawled-property

I have a managed metadata column named TELL Category.  My understanding is all columns have a crawled property and if the column is a managed metadata column it is automatically mapped to a managed property when it is crawled.  In the image below, it appears that a managed property was created. I can't seem to surface it in a custom display template.

Additionally, TELL Category is listed twice in the list of crawled properties.  Any idea why this is the case?  How should I approach this?  It's not clear to me what the additional mappings are... What is ExcludeFromSummary?

[image]

Comment: What does the SharePoint Search tool say, are the any values in those autogenerated managed properties?

Comment: Could you explain?  How can I check to see if there are values in the autogenerated managed properties?  Second question... I've customized my item display template.  I'm confident it is correct.  I haven't touched the control template.  Is there a need to do so?

Comment: The SharePoint Search query is a must have tool when working with Search, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointsearch/2015/04/09/sharepoint-online-using-sharepoint-search-query-tool-to-look-at-managed-properties/. And No, in most cases there is no need to to change the control template.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a new managed property, ensure that it can be retrieved and queryed (and perhaps refinable if you need that) and map it to the not-taxid version. Add that managed property to you item display template and voila. (sorry if some of the details are slightly off, I rarely see an on-premises SharePoint these days)

Comment: Kasper.. for some reason I thought I was supposed to use the taxid version?  I just checked.. They all seem to be taxid.  I'll check again.  Another question.... When entering the managed property into the display template is it case sensitive.  Is owstaxIdTELLCategory with a capital I or lower case i  ?